# Redireccionar en Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy desarrollando en Laravel un sistema que dependiendo el correo que ingrese es a la sección que lo redireccione. En el archivo *LoginController* ingreso el siguiente código para que lo realice, pero no esta funcionando:

```
if (auth()->user()->email = 'terapeuta@mail.com') {
        return '/admin/atenciones';
    }
    if (auth()->user()->email = 'admin@mail.com') {

    return '/admin';
 }
}
```

Agradezco a quien me pueden oriente un poco con esto.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? yo veo que la comparación está mal hecha, debería ser con un doble igual `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes mal el if amigo, el = representa asignación, si quieres validar si es igual debes user ==
En tu caso debe quedar así

```
$view = "";
if (auth()->user()->email == 'terapeuta@mail.com') {
    $view = '/admin/atenciones';
}
if (auth()->user()->email == 'admin@mail.com') {
    $view = '/admin';
}
return $view;
```

Es más elegante si manejas un solo return, se ve mucho mejor el código y es más entendible

Comment: Recomendación: No respondas por favor a preguntas cuyo error es un typo ya que terminan cerradas y tu aporte se perdería